# How to prevent autologin of GUI?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, login

I have found this thread on how to switch boot default behaviour on Raspbian Jessie from boot to command-line to boot to GUI and back.

Booting to command-line:

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

Booting to GUI:

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

However, the same thread also indicates how to disable autologin, and while I got this to work for booting to command-line (and switching it back to autologin), booting to GUI always autologins. Are these commands incorrect?

Manual login:

```
ln -fs /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service
```

Autologin:

```
ln -fs /etc/systemd/system/autologin@.service /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service
```

Comment: n.b. `raspi-config` supports a `nonint` mode. If you want to configure this as part of a script, issue `raspi-config nonint do_boot_behaviour Bn`, where `n` is 1-4 depending on the boot mode you need.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can easily be done with `raspi-config`.

1. Run the command `sudo raspi-config`
2. Select *Boot Options*
3. Choose *Desktop*
4. Exit the prompt and restart the RPi

---

**Edit:**

To address you wanting to do this from the command line for a bash script, I suggest we look at the actual source of `raspi-config` (which is written in bash).

```bash
if [ $SYSTEMD -eq 1 ]; then
  systemctl set-default multi-user.target
  ln -fs /etc/systemd/system/autologin@.service /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service
else
  [ -e /etc/init.d/lightdm ] && update-rc.d lightdm disable 2
  sed /etc/inittab -i -e "s/1:2345:respawn:\/sbin\/getty --noclear 38400 tty1/1:2345:respawn:\/bin\/login -f pi tty1 <\/d$
fi
```

Comment: This works, but how do I do it from the command-line directly? My purpose is to have a bash script doing this.

Comment: @tlhIngan: I added an excerpt from the raspi-config script.

Comment: The answer was in the raspi-config source. The commands I was using from the other thread obvisouly came from here, but the GUI boot needs an additional command.

Comment: For posterity, the additional command for enabling/disabling the GUI autologin is, after the ln -fs command, `sed /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf -i -e "s/^autologin-user=pi/#autologin-user=/"` to disable autologin, and `sed /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf -i -e "s/^#autologin-user=,*/autologin-user=pi/"` to re-enable it.

Comment: @Jacobm001 the `raspi-config` does not work in my case. Everytime I perform the same steps on Jessie 8.0 it wont boot to CLI. It always boots to GUI. 

However when this sudo `systemctl set-default multi-user.target` only then it boots to CLI on boot

Comment: It has an option login as ctrl-alt-delor but not for other users. I want it to login as one of the other users.