# Auto login in Jessie. How?

Tags: raspbian-jessie, login, systemd

I want to auto login to the terminal after boot (Jessie).

I tried the instructions here (http://elinux.org/RPi_Debian_Auto_Login), but it didn't work. I think the problem is the new systemd init structure in Jessie.

So, is there any method to auto login to the terminal in Jessie !?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent autologin of GUI?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47823/how-to-prevent-autologin-of-gui)

Answer (score 22):

Enter the command `sudo raspi-config`.
Scroll down to `Boot Options` and select `Console Autologin`. Then exit the configuration menu and reboot.

Comment: @Hack-R this answer is over a year old. When I wrote it, there was no intermediate screen. Feel free to edit it and add the new menu.

Comment: This action should be used with prudence (if you have removed the `pi` user probably you will have issues like this: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/64189/raspbian-authentication-failure-for-automatic-login)

Answer (score 2):

Look at [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47823/how-to-prevent-autologin-of-gui), it shows how to enable and disable autologin, both for the GUI and the command-line; `raspi-config` also does it.

Answer (score 2):

I found this, the only thing that worked for me.

#### Automatic Login for LightDM

Open the terminal and make first a backup of the file we are going to edit:

```
su - 
gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.back
```

Edit now this file:

```
gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

or

```
nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Uncomment these two lines:

```
autologin-user=USERNAME
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

Replace USERNAME with your own username. Save the file and exit. Run now this command so that changes are taken into effect:

```
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```