# Raspbian authentication failure for automatic login

Tags: boot

My Raspberry Pi has been booting into the GUI for almost a year now. I wanted to change this, so I used `raspi-config` to set the boot mode to 'Text console, automatically logged in.'

After a restart however, my Pi seems to be bricked. Booting prompts me with the error messages in the image below and the Pi does not respond to keyboard input. I can still access the safe mode.

Is there a way to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Did you change the default password?

Comment: @shaggs Yes, pretty sure I once did.

Comment: Just as a trial change the password back to raspberry (default) just to see if it works

Comment: @shaggs But how do I change the password if I cannot access the system?

Comment: Can you do it if you accesw to safe mode still

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with a vanilla SD-card on which I did put Raspbian Buster on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error occurred because the default login mechanism tries to default login via the `pi` user. You must have deleted or changed it in some way that the OS can't recognize it anymore. The solution would be to tell the OS to default login to a different user.

First of all. Login to a terminal from the error screen using `Ctrl+Alt+F1`. Log in to the desired user.

Now when you have a functioning terminal, it's time to change the default user. The solution would be to create a task that automatically defaults to your preferred user:

```
sudo mkdir -pv /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf
```

In the file insert the following (note that the default username needs to be placed there as well)

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin YOUR_DEFAULT_USER_HERE --noclear %I 38400 linux
```

Restart the raspberry and you should be good to go.

**Edit**:
The error originally occurred because debian stopped using the inittab mechanism and started using `systemd`. For additional information you can checkout a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/679419/how-to-make-auto-login-work-in-ubuntu-no-display-manager)