# Enable autologin by modyfing image on SD card

Tags: raspbian, image, login

My problem is simple. I don't have keyboard, so I am unable to type password when booting raspberry with fresh image. Which file on the card (and how) should I edit to enable autologin to the Raspbian?

Or maybe is there some tool eliglibe to `raspi-config` which can I run from computer which I used to prepare card?

Comment: Since you have no keyboard, is it safe to assume you're running headless, or do you have a desktop running on a display? Do you have a linux computer available? If not, what sort of desktop do you have? The necessary files are on the ext4 root partition, so you need to be able to mount it to modify them.

Comment: I have installed RASPBIAN STRETCH LITE image. I am running Mac. Such problem doesn't occur with the desktop version?

Comment: The procedure is different for logging into the command line versus a full desktop. Although you can load drivers to allow mounting of ext4 volumes on your Mac, it might be easiest to boot a linux virtual machine (e.g. using vbox) on your Mac. Alternately, do you have a keyboard and display you could connect temporarily?

Comment: What might help you is to enable SSH on your build first: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4444/enabling-ssh-on-rpi-without-screen-keystrokes-for-raspi-config 
Then you could SSH into your pi and change the files you need to get auto-login working: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/48241/auto-login-in-jessie-how

Comment: Even better than my first link, to enable SSH simply put a file named 'SSH' into the Boot partition. Taken from here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/

Comment: @bobstro nope. I have no keyboard, that's the reason why I am asking question :)

Comment: So... how do you plan to edit the files? Assuming on another system, my answer below should get you going. (This is surely a duplicate question by now.)

Answer (score 4):

You can configure your system to automatically log into the command line by creating a file in `/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf` with the following content:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin yourname --noclear %I $TERM
```

You will need RW access to the filesystem. If you can't log into the RPi directly, you can mount the partitions on the card on another system that can mount ext4 partitions (ideally linux) to make these edits. Otherwise, connect the network and make these changes as root.